# Reading attribute values using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes, values

What is the way to  get the information contained in the attribute table, say in column 2, row 2 using PyQGIS?

Comment: This is helpful, but this only seems to give you the value of the attributes. It seems attributes need to be a name/value pair. How do you get the name for each attribute? Is that what the "fields" is all about?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 63):

To loop over every feature in a layer, use the [`getFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab0aee12fd9ff7c20b6587d6019f19edc) generator. This returns an iterator of features ([`QgsFeature`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html)) in the layer.

```py
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    pass # do something with feature
```

If you're only interested in a particular feature, instead of all of the features in the layer, you can access it using the [`QgsFeatureRequest`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html) and its `"FID"`:

```py
fid = 1 # the second feature (zero-based indexing!)
iterator = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(fid))
feature = next(iterator)
```

Once you have a `QgsFeature` object you can use the [`attributes()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a5a473f89868c234d53cea67504cd2f2e) method to retrieve the attributes (a.k.a. columns or fields) associated with that feature (a.k.a. row), e.g.:

```py
# get the feature's attributes
attrs = feature.attributes()
# print the second attribute (note zero-based indexing of Python lists)
print(attrs[1])
```

If you want to index the field by its name, rather than a number, you need to use the field mappings:

```py
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
print(feature.attributes()[idx])
```

The field index shouldn't change during the loop, so you only need to call it once.

There is more information and examples in the PyQGIS cookbook:
http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer

You can access feature attributes much more easily by using the `QgsFeature` like a `dict`, e.g.

```py
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    name = feature["name"]
```

I'm not sure which version came in or if it's always been there.

Answer (score 20):

In order to get the information in a table you would first have to *access the layer's features*. In my case, I put the features in a variable.

Then you *loop through the features*, and for each feature you *call its attributes*, which can then be printed using their *column index*.

For example, if I would like to get all the values in the second column (which corresponds to the first index), then I would do this:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

features = layer.getFeatures()

for feat in features:
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    print(attrs[1])
```

It uses the [`getFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab0aee12fd9ff7c20b6587d6019f19edc) method of the `QgsVectorLayer` class and the [`attributes()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a5a473f89868c234d53cea67504cd2f2e) method of the `QgsFeature` class.

Answer (score 8):

The answers above only show how to do this for the active layer. I would think, in many cases, you might want to find said attribute for a layer that is not the active layer or a layer checked in the Layers window.

The code below will get a list of all layers that you have added to your Layers window (regardless if they are checked or active) and find the attribute at row 2, column 2.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("myLayerName")[0]
value = layer.getFeature(2).attribute(2)
```

Note [`mapLayersByName()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a935efacacb942a15afe19728233e35c3) returns a list of layers with the given name. I am assuming one exists for this example.