# check particular feature exists using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

I want to check that a particular features exists or not in getFeature().

*Suppose in attribute table I have ID, Name, CAT, and Type columns. Now I want to check that CATEGORY column is exists or not in features.*

I use this but this is not working.

```
for poi in layerPOI.getFeatures():
    if "CATEGORY"  in layerPOI.getFeatures():
```

and this as well. It producing keyError

```
if poi["CATEGORY"]#As category not exists it giving error here
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you want to check if it exists? Do you want to see if it contains a certain value or a specific value in a specific field...?

Comment: want to check specific feature name exists or not

Comment: You could use some of the methods described in this post: [How to read the attribute values using PyQGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54057/how-to-read-the-attribute-values-using-pyqgis). And add an `if` statement to see if the feature exists by matching it to an id or name.

Comment: what are the some of the methods. i have already used if it give me error in if condition

Comment: The term **layerPOI.getFeatures()** is an iterator and **poi** is a **QgsFeature** object. You cannot do `if "CATEGORY"  in layerPOI.getFeatures()` again.

Comment: @xunilk so how to check that man. a particular feature name is exists in the features or not

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/212618/edit) your question to show an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: @Joseph updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if 'CATEGORY' exists as a field:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

field = 'CATEGORY' 

index = layer.fieldNameIndex(field)

if index == -1:
    print "field doesn't exist"
else:
    print "field exists"
```