# KeyError but field exists (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis

I have 10 fields in my shapefile, and I want to use Python (3.7) to access the value of one field in QGIS.

When I run my code (below) I get a **KeyError: '6'** (index position of the field), implying that the field lookup worked, but that once I try to access the value, the field doesn't exist.

```
f = layer.getFeature(fid)
index = layer.fields().lookupField('length')
print("length: ", f[index])
```

I also tried:

```
f = layer.getFeature(fid)
index = layer.fields().indexFromName('length')
print("length: ", f[index])
```

Both throw the same error.

Sample code uses just in a print statement, but I need to use the index number at various points/for different methods.

**Clarification:** the field look up returns index 6, which is the correct index corresponding to the field length. It's only when I go to use that index number that I then get a Key Error stating that the field doesn't exist.

```
point_layer = iface.addVectorLayer("...file path.shp", "points", 'ogr')
main_layer = iface.activeLayer()

...more code making lists...

for v_id in list:  
    idx = point_layer.fields().lookupField('segment_id')
    v = point_layer.getFeature(v_id)

    segment_id = v[idx]
    s = main_layer.getFeature(segment_id)

    idx = layer.fields().lookupField('length')

    print("length: ", s.attributes()[idx]) #throws IndexError: list index out of range
    print("length: ", s[idx]) #throws KeyError
```

**Image:** Works through console - I know the field index is right and the value exists

[image]

Comment: you are using `index`and after is `idx`

Comment: Try `f.attributes()[idx]` (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a5a473f89868c234d53cea67504cd2f2e and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54059/2856)

Comment: @FranRaga corrected, just an error in my code transcribed here

Comment: @jyingling - Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/312420/edit) your question to show how you defined `layer` and `fid`?

Comment: @Joseph updated

Comment: @jyingling - Would it be possible to upload a reproducable example? The code you posted seems to have three layers where they're either being read for features and/or indices which makes it a little confusing :)

Comment: @Joseph - sorry, error in code transcribed here. Fixed, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: my segment IDs weren't matching the actual feature IDs, so it was returning a key error because the previous code wasn't returning a feature.

```
for v_id in no_dup:
    v = point_layer.getFeature(v_id)

    seg_id = v[seg_idx]
    s_list = list(main_layer.getFeatures("seg_id = {}".format(seg_id)))
    s = s_list[0]

    len_idx = main_layer.fields().lookupField('length') 
    print("length: ", s[len_idx])
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simpler:

```
print("length: ", f['length'])
```

Comment: The goal of my code is not actually to print the value, I need to use other methods that require an index value and are also throwing the key error.

Comment: @jyingling please update the question to reflect this requirement

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
print("length: ", f.attributes()[index])
```

or loop all features

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()             
index = layer.fields().indexFromName('length')
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    print (f.attributes()[index])
```

Comment: Threw IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @jyingling, so the value of your fid variable do not correspond with any featureID of the layer?

Comment: Clarified @GabrielDeLuca