# Opening .gdbtable file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I am trying to open the .gdbtable file in QGIS.

I  have tried:

`'open data source' -> vector -> vector databese -> a0000000a.gdbtable -> open`

It gives me following error.

`a0000000a.gdbtable is not a valid or recognized data source`

Comment: Open data source - vector - directory and in the type drop down use ESRI FileGDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File geodatabase is not a flat file data source.  You cannot point to a single file and have it read by any application (for the reason that the descriptors for the file contents are not present in it). The other 42+ files are critical to the ability to read the file, and the parent directory ***must*** have a suffix of `.gdb`.

If you were only given this one file, you must ask the provider to give you either a complete file geodatabase with the table you want in it, or to provide a CSV or some other geo-format with the data.

If you were given a zipfile and extracted just one file, you must go back and extract the entire contents to local disk. Then you can "open" the `.gdb` parent folder, and the table(s) should be present.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. would it possible to open the file in ARCGIS?

Comment: No, not as a singleton file.  You need the whole directory, or a different format.

Comment: I have downloaded the data from the following link: https://cms.agr.wa.gov/WSDAKentico/Documents/DO/NRAS/WSDACropDistribution-gdb.zip                                                                                                                                   I cannot see any mother .gdb file

Comment: I see a zipfile with .gdb folder containing 50 files, a normal file geodatabase. ArcMap sees  a table ("CropData" with 16 columns and 226971 rows) and a polygon feature class ("WSDACrop_2020" with 10 columns (12 with length/area) and 226971 rows). The other tables are hidden data dictionary, aka "catalog", reference tables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have sorted this out. I basically took  out all the files in a separate folder. Since, the new  folder was not in .gdb format, I was facing that issue.  Thank you for your time

Answer (score -1):

Just trying to extend the answer a bit more, and im reading between the lines of what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

She mentions 'gdbtable' suggesting that the OP is wanting just the attribute information from the GDB. (im guessing here).

As a suggestion - if you have the File Geodatabase open in QGIS, you can use code to just retrieve attribute information, something similar to:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

features = lyr.getFeatures()

for feat in features:
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    print(attrs[1])
```

There is some further discussion here:
[How to read the attribute values using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54057/how-to-read-the-attribute-values-using-pyqgis)

Ideally, you could programmatically get pyQGIS to 'open' the File Geodatabase and use the above code to retrieve attribute schema and values.